# How to make the cloth object simulate out of my collision body in blender?

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

[image]

I am simulating a cloth over a body obj. I have a problem with my cloth getting inside of the body before the start of the simulation. If I apply cloth physics to the shirt and collision physics to the body obj, some part of the cloth gets stuck inside the body obj. What parameter should I adjust to make the cloth come out and behave normally?

Thanks